# Converting utc time string to datetime object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the Paypal API and I get back a timestamp in the following format. I try to parse this to a datetime object using strptime, but I get the following error:

```
(Pdb) datetime.strptime('2012-03-01T10:00:00Z','%Y-%M-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
*** error: redefinition of group name 'M' as group 5; was group 2
```

Also, as this format is supposed to be quite a standard format isn't there a function available for this?

EDIT:

Ok seems to be a typo. First %M should be %m

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing `%M` (minute) and `%m` (month).

Answer (score 69):

The parser from dateutil is your friend.

You'll have to pip install dateutil but you've save bags and bags of date conversion code:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

You can use it like this.

```
from dateutil import parser
ds = '2012-03-01T10:00:00Z' # or any date sting of differing formats.
date = parser.parse(ds)
```

You'll find you can deal with almost any date string formats with this parser and you'll get a nice standard python date back

Comment: Please up vote and change this to your fav answer then please @arno_v

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you use `%M` twice. Use `%m` for the months:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2012-03-01T10:00:00Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 10, 0)
```

Comment: Why should I use time? Makes sense to use datetime here right? Since this is both a date and a time.

Comment: @arno_v: I see, you're using the class method `datetime.strptime`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo.  `%M` is used twice.  You meant to use `%m` for the month.  From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].   
%M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].
```