# Converting unicode string of time into datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert `Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:19:08 -0700 (PDT)` into a datetime object. It's currently unicode

This is my first time doing this but it isn't working:

```
time = 'Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:19:08 -0700 (PDT)'
date_object = datetime.strptime(time, %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %X (%Z))
```

I am getting this error:

```
  File "quickstart1.py", line 206
    date_object = datetime.strptime(time, %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %X (%Z))
```

Comment: Are you certain that's the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> date_object = parse(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings must be strings.

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %X (%Z)')
```

Comment: ahh ok. Got this error: sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 8; was group 5. What is group 8 or 5?

Comment: @MorganAllen are you using Python 3?

Comment: I thought I was. But when I checked, 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)  is running. However, I have to do print('test') instead of print test....

Comment: So you should use a third party named [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to parse a date string with timezone information. Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433851/converting-utc-time-string-to-datetime-object